# Time calculation Timeformat minus

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have an code that shows how much hours sombody worked on that specific day.

```
SELECT ur.id,us.username, '' as callback_del,datum, ur.description,
        DATE_FORMAT(ur.time_from, '%H:%i') as nosearch_tijdvan,
        DATE_FORMAT(ur.time_till, '%H:%i') as nosearch_tijdtot,
        DATE_FORMAT(break, '%H:%i') as nosearch_pauze,
        TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(time_from,time_till), '%H:%i') as nosearch_diff,   
        TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(time_from,time_till)  - break, '%H:%i') AS nosearch_totaal
        FROM " . uren . " AS ur
        JOIN " . project . " AS pr ON pr.project_id = ur.project_id
        JOIN " . user . " AS us ON us.userid = ur.userid
```

For example

time_from = 07:00:00

time_till = 16:00:00

break = 01:00:00 hour

> the output = 08:00:00 hours worked

but if the break = 00:30:00 hours

> The output = NULL

Does sombody have any solution for the problem

Thanks

Comment: Only use blockquotes for actual quotes and use bold sparingly for emphasis, not to attract attention, so please remove it.

Comment: What datatypes are your `time_from`, `time_till`, and `break` columns in your table?  What do you want to do when a worker starts working at `23:00` and works till `07:00` the next calendar day? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
TIMEDIFF(TIMEDIFF(time_from,time_till), break)
```

instead of

```
(TIMEDIFF(time_from,time_till)  - break)
```